Find Conjunctive Normal Form of a compound proposition
I want to find CNF (Conjunctive Normal Formula) of the following proposition:
$(¬p∨¬q∨¬r)→¬ ((a→¬b) ∨q)$
My attempt: If I use the result that $p→q ≡¬p ∨q$ then
$(¬p∨¬q∨¬r)→¬ (¬a∨¬b ∨q)$. Again if I use $p→q ≡¬p ∨q$ then
$¬ (¬p∨¬q∨¬r) ∨ (¬a∨¬b ∨q). $
I am not getting any conjunction sign here. Unable to proceed after that. Kindly help.

Use de Morgan's law on the left disjunct, then distribute. Also, you removed a $\neg$ on the right disjunct.

$\quad(\neg p\lor\neg q\lor\neg r)\to\neg((a\to\neg b)\lor q)\\
=\neg(\neg p\lor\neg q\lor\neg r)\lor\neg(\neg a\lor\neg b\lor q)\quad(x\to y=\neg x\lor y)\\
=(p\land q\land r)\lor(a\land b\land\neg q)\quad\text{(de Morgan's law)}\\
=(q\lor(a\land b))\land(\neg q\lor(p\land r))\quad ((z\land x)\lor(\neg z\land y)=(z\lor y)\land(\neg z\lor x))\\
=((q\lor a)\land(q\lor b))\land((\neg q\lor p)\land(\neg q\lor r))\quad\text{(Distributivity)}\\
=(q\lor a)\land(q\lor b)\land(\neg q\lor p)\land(\neg q\lor r)$
